# get_the_date() returns english Year & Day when language is Arabic

Tags: plugin-development, date, multi-language, date-time

I changed my WordPress language to Arabic, Now `get_the_date()` returns `يناير 30, 2020` (half Arabic & half english) but I need to get date full Arabic like: `يناير ٣٠, ٢٠٢٠`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has [date_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/) to retrieve the date in localised format, based on timestamp.

Try:

```
echo date_i18n("d F Y (H:i)",$date) ;
```

Comment: `date_i18n` returns the same English & Arabic mixed value

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else needed this, these two functions displays post date and time in arabic for a wordpress website:

DATE:

functions.php

```
function single_post_arabic_date($postdate_d,$postdate_d2,$postdate_m,$postdate_y) {
    $months = array("Jan" => "يناير", "Feb" => "فبراير", "Mar" => "مارس", "Apr" => "أبريل", "May" => "مايو", "Jun" => "يونيو", "Jul" => "يوليو", "Aug" => "أغسطس", "Sep" => "سبتمبر", "Oct" => "أكتوبر", "Nov" => "نوفمبر", "Dec" => "ديسمبر");
    $en_month = $postdate_m;
    foreach ($months as $en => $ar) {
        if ($en == $en_month) { $ar_month = $ar; }
    }

    $find = array ("Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" , "Thu", "Fri");
    $replace = array ("السبت", "الأحد", "الإثنين", "الثلاثاء", "الأربعاء", "الخميس", "الجمعة");
    $ar_day_format = $postdate_d2;
    $ar_day = str_replace($find, $replace, $ar_day_format);

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $standard = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
    $eastern_arabic_symbols = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩");
    $post_date = $ar_day.' '.$postdate_d.' '.$ar_month.' '.$postdate_y;
    $arabic_date = str_replace($standard , $eastern_arabic_symbols , $post_date);

    return $arabic_date;
}
```

```
<date>
<?php
  $postdate_d = get_the_date('d');
  $postdate_d2 = get_the_date('D');
  $postdate_m = get_the_date('M');
  $postdate_y = get_the_date('Y');                                

 echo single_post_arabic_date($postdate_d,$postdate_d2, $postdate_m, $postdate_y);
?>
</date>
```

TIME:

functions.php

```
function single_post_arabic_time($posttime_h, $posttime_i, $posttime_a) {

    $ampm = array("AM", "PM");
    $ampmreplace = array("ق.ظ", "ب.ظ");
    $ar_ampm = str_replace($ampm, $ampmreplace, $posttime_a);

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $standardletters = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    $eastern_arabic_letters = array("٠", "١", "٢", "٣", "٤", "٥", "٦", "٧", "٨", "٩");
    $post_time = $posttime_h . ':' . $posttime_i." ".$ar_ampm;
    $arabic_time = str_replace($standardletters, $eastern_arabic_letters, $post_time);

    return $arabic_time;
}
```

```
<time>
<?php
  $posttime_h = get_the_date('h');
  $posttime_i = get_the_date('i');
  $posttime_s = get_the_date('d');
  $posttime_a = get_the_date('A');

echo single_post_arabic_time($posttime_h,$posttime_i,$posttime_a);
?>
</time>
```

Comment: That means I need to write this function manually for every language?